# Gedmo SoftdeleatableListener : No mapping found for field 'deletedAt'

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit, listener, soft-delete

I want to disable Gedmo\SoftDeleatable behaviour for some of my phpunit tests in Symfony2.

I wrote these lines to remove SoftDeleatableListener:

```
foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $eventName => $listeners) {
    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener) {
            $em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($eventName, $listener);
        }
    }
}
```

But none of the listeners was identified as being an instance of SoftDeleteableListener.

So I added these lines in app/config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    ..
    orm:
        ..
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: false
```

and these lines in Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    ..
    gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

But when I run php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql, 
I get the following error message:

> No mapping found for field 'deletedAt' on class 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Account'.

Any idea ?

Comment: Please show ORM mapping for your `Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Account` entity. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you still need to add the property to the class.

```
  /**
  * @var \DateTime
  * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
  */
  protected $deletedAt;
```

I have used the `Trait`. Only this Trait does not define the `deletedAt`. Where the trait TimestampableEntity defines the columns.

```
use SoftDeleteable;
```

I hope this helps